# Comparing the tails of two related convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, asymptotics

Let $b_1,b_2,\dots$ be positive real numbers such that 
$$s_1<\infty\quad\text{and}\quad z_1<\infty, 
$$
where 
$$s_k:=\sum_{j=k}^\infty b_j\quad\text{and}\quad z_k:=\sum_{j=k}^\infty\frac{b_j}{\sqrt{s_j}} 
$$
for natural $k$. Does it then necessarily follow that 
$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{z_k}{\sqrt{s_k}}<\infty\,\text{?}
$$
(One may note here that $z_k\ge\sqrt{s_k}$ for all $k$, whence $\liminf_{k\to\infty}\frac{z_k}{\sqrt{s_k}}\ge1$.)

---

(This question is a "discretized" version of a problem considered in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/348149/36721).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact $z_k$ (or better any partial sum for it) is a lower Riemann sum for the function ${1\over \sqrt{x}}$ wrto the infinitesimal decreasing sequence $s_k>s_{k+1}>\dots s_{m} $, so $z_k< \int_0^{s_k}{1\over \sqrt{x}}dx=2\sqrt{s_k}$, and  the constant $2$ is sharp.

Comment: It is this simple!

Answer (score 3):

Let us prove the following, stronger claim: 
$$z_k<2\sqrt{s_k}\tag{1}$$
for all natural $k$. Also, the condition $z_1<\infty$ will not be needed or used.

Take indeed any natural $k$. Letting 
$$h_i:=\frac1{\sqrt{s_{i+1}}}-\frac1{\sqrt{s_i}},
$$
we have 
$$\frac1{\sqrt{s_j}}=\frac1{\sqrt{s_k}}+\sum_{i=k}^{j-1}h_i
$$
for all natural $j\ge k$. 
So, 
\begin{align}z_k&=\sum_{j=k}^\infty\frac{s_j-s_{j+1}}{\sqrt{s_j}} \\ 
&=\sum_{j=k}^\infty(s_j-s_{j+1})\Big(\frac1{\sqrt{s_k}}+\sum_{i=k}^{j-1}h_i\Big) \\ 
&=s_k\,\frac1{\sqrt{s_k}}+\sum_{i=k}^\infty h_i\sum_{j=i+1}^\infty(s_j-s_{j+1}) \\
&=\sqrt{s_k}+\sum_{i=k}^\infty\Big(\frac1{\sqrt{s_{i+1}}}-\frac1{\sqrt{s_i}}\Big)s_{i+1} \\ 
&<\sqrt{s_k}+\sum_{i=k}^\infty(\sqrt{s_i}-\sqrt{s_{i+1}})=2\sqrt{s_k}. 
\end{align}
So, we have (1), as claimed.

---

The constant factor $2$ in (1) cannot be improved. Indeed, take any $a\in(0,1)$ and for all natural $j$ let $b_j=a^j$, so that $s_j=b_j/(1-a)$ and $z_j=(1+\sqrt a)\sqrt{s_j}$. It remains to let $a$ be arbitrarily close to $1$.